# Formatting a set of date columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below date formats as object type
when I am trying to convert into date , it is giving me outOfBoundsDateTime error and I am not able to convert it into correct format.

| date_1 | date_2 | date_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0020-01-31 | 0020-01-31 | 2020-01-31 |
| 0021-01-01 | 0021-12-31 | 2021-02-28 |
| 0021-01-01 | 0021-12-31 | 2021-02-28 |

Here is the tried code:

```
import pandas as pd
for column in my_df[['date_1', 'date_2','date_3']]:
    new_column=pd.to_datetime(global_events_df[column]).dt.date
```

Error :

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 20-01-31 00:00:00
```

anyone faced this similar issue, please guide

Comment: The first two columns year is 20?

Comment: yes right, the first part in date represent year 2020

Comment: But it is ```0020``` which doesn't mean it is year ```2020```. You have to convert ```0020``` to ```2020``` first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0020-01-31` exceeds the range of the pandas datetime supported by a 64-bit integer.

Belows are the max and min value of datetime that pandas supports:

```
>>> pd.Timestamp.max
Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')
>>> pd.Timestamp.min
Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145224193')
```

So, your options are

1. change `0020` to `2020` and `0021` to `2021`
2. use `pd.to_datetime(<your_datetime>, errors = 'coerce')` to represent them with `NaT`